# Mock a class's local method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I am trying write test case in Rpec for a Class which look like this

```
class ABC
   def method_1( arg )
       #does something and return a value based on arg
   end

   def initialize
       @service = method_1( arg )
   end

   def getSomething_1
       return @service.get_seomthing_1
   end

   def getSomething_2
       return @service.get_seomthing_2
   end
end
```

Now I want to initiate the @service instance variable with a mocked object so that I can use that mocked object to return values against which I can validate my unit tests.

I tried to do something like

```
describe ABC do
    before(:each) do
       myObject = double()
       myObject.stub(:get_something_1).and_return("SomeValue")
       ABC.any_instance.stub(:method_1).and_return(myObject)
    end

   it "Checks the correctness of getSomething_1 method of class ABC" do
       @abc = ABC.new
       @abc.getSomething_1.should eql("SomeValue")
   end
end
```

NOw when I am trying to run the test @service is not getting initialized with the object with which I want it to.
Seems like method_1 is not getting mocked with the behaviour defined. 
Can someone help with how to assign @service with my mocked object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is you're stubbing `:method_1`, which allows you to control what it *returns*, but while short-circuiting its *behaviour*. Unfortunately, what `method_1` returns is irrelevant, it's what it *does*—assigning `@service`—that's interesting.

Without seeing the actual interface and design of your class, I can't suggest improvements on that score, but you can at least get your expectation to work correctly by substituting references to an instance variable (ie. `@service.some_method`) with an attr_reader:

```
class ABC
  attr_reader :service

  # ...

  def getSomething_1
    return service.get_seomthing_1
  end
end
```

And then in your spec:

```
describe ABC
  # ..

  before do
    ABC.any_instance(:service).and_return(myObject)
    # ...
  end

  it "Checks the correctness of getSomething_1 method of class ABC" do
    @abc = ABC.new("xyz")
    @abc.getSomething_1.should eql("SomeValue")
  end
end
```

In this case, any instance of `ABC` will return your mock when its attribute `service` is called, allowing `getSomething_1` to correctly reference your mock.

Comment: What my method_1 does is that it initiates a service client and service.get_seomthing_1 is an API call of the service, so what I tried to cut off the network dependency and initiate service with my mock object.

Comment: your approach of attr_reader worked, i also thought of similar approach by writing a function to set my service variable.
but i am confused why stubbing service worked because it will also behave as a local function call in the class.

Answer (score 0):

You're really close, but it looks like you're incorrectly stubbing :method_1 on an instance of ABC. You need to do something like:

```
before(:each) do
  myObject = double(get_something_1: "SomeValue")
  ABC.any_instance().should_receive(:method_1).and_return(myObject)
end
```

Comment: I think what you did in your reply is just another way of stubing no different from how I did.

Comment: @manyu I tested my example and it works. I'm not sure at this point what your question is.

Comment: can you tell me how defining the mock like you defined i.e double(get_something_1: "SomeValue") 
is different from 
myObject = double()
myObject.stub(:get_something_1).and_return("SomeValue")

Comment: I'm not sure there's a difference, it's just shorthand. The issue though is that you're not actually stubbing :method_1 in your example. You can either use `should_receive` as I show, or `stub` as shown in [the documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-14/docs/method-stubs/stub-on-any-instance-of-a-class).